# pmtk-3 left-right Hidden Markov Models

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, speech-recognition, hidden-markov-models

I have created a ergodic hmm in matlab using Kevin Murphy's machine learning toolkit pmtk3. The thing is the ergodic hmm's work fine but I want to create a left-right hmm's for my data to compare results. I am unsure how to do this correctly. I tried initializing the state transition matrix where I do not allow previous states e.g 3 state HMM state transition matrix:

```
transmat = [0.5 0.4 0.0; 0.0 0.6 0.4; 0.0 0.0 1.0];
```

this doesn't work, it throws an error:

```
Error using chol
Matrix must be positive definite.
```

I am lost here, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

EDIT: Library I am using is here https://github.com/probml/pmtk3

Comment: are you asking a question about a custom library/code you've used? In that case at least link the resources - or even better, ask the author the question.

Comment: Hi GameOfThrows I have added a link to the toolkit. Ya its a general question about the tookit. Just wondering has anyone created a left-right HMM with this.

Comment: You may want to ask the library creator on github

Comment: Hi Ander Biguri, will try...

Answer (score 0):

make sure the rows sum to 1.
0.5 0.4 0.0 doesn't ... then try again.